# Change main content without changing the full page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am in need of help people, please help.

I have a software documentation website that i am building, similar to the mongodb documentation page where there is a header, a sidebar which is the navbar menu and a main where the main content live. In the sidebar nav menu i have drop-down menus that i would like click to change the main content with another html page without me getting out of the current full page. The way mongodb does, if you click on the sidebar menu the content in the main changes accordingly and the url changes as well but the sidebar and the header are unaffected. Can someone help or i explain all this so wrong?

Comment: Start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+main+content+navbar+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the buttons on the sidebar do trigger an html request to get the new data to display. Then it changes the main content using javascript. I usually prefer to use vanilla Js, but some might prefer some framework like Vue Js in order to do the dynamic change.